# Append multiple images in Form-data is working in java script?

Tags: javascript, form-data

I wanna Post multiple input files (Images). I have used FormData its taking only one file after submitting.

```
uploadCategoryImages = () => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    let imagefile = document.querySelector('#contained-button-file')
    for(let i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        formData.append('image', imagefile.files[i])
        console.log(imagefile.files[i])
    }        
}
```

Comment: This isn't really a question yet. what have you tried? how does it fail? what is the expected result? please have a look here and update your question please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have not change para name you have sent in your form Data.Please find below code :

```js
uploadCategoryImages = () => {
    let formData = new FormData()
    let imagefile = document.querySelector('#contained-button-file')
    for(let i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        formData.append('image_'+i, imagefile.files[i],imagefile.files[i].name)
        console.log(imagefile.files[i])
    }        
}
```

Comment: imagefile.files[i].name -> this is name is showing error...B

Comment: Can your please share error which is facing by you?

Comment: I want to post multiple images but formdata actually uploading only one

Comment: Please add name attribute in your input file with any feasible name that's why you are facing error near "imagefile.files[i].name".

Comment: And in your code when you are calling function "uploadCategoryImages"?

Comment: I have added still i am geting error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryFileName' of undefined" like this

Comment: There is a button below input file onClicking the button the selected images need to post

Comment: Please provide your complete code so I can help you in fast way.

Comment: Sure i ll share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181667/discussion-between-kishan-and-ramya-miim).

Answer (score 0):

> I have used FormData its taking only one file after submitting.

The odds are that you are misinterpreting the problem and the server side code you are submitting to is only trying to read one value.

PHP is a classic for this. If you want to post multiple values with the same name, then the *client* has to use a name ending in `[]`:

```
formData.append('image[]', imagefile.files[i])
```

… which will then give you an array:

```
$array = $_FILES['image']
```

Other languages often have form libraries with different methods used to get a single value or multiple values. Take Perl's CGI module for example:

```
formData.append('image', imagefile.files[i])
```

and

```
my $value = $q->param('image');
my @values = $q->multi_param('image');
```